# Regular expression to match String has unique uppercase letters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying check if string is of length 3 and has unique uppercase characters and followed by 4 digit year from 1900 to 2019, I came up with the below expression but its failing to identify if the string has duplicate characters. can someone please help me fix this?

```
^(?:([A-Z]{3})(?!.*\1))(19\d{2}|20[0-1]\d)$
```

example: `ABC1990 should be matched and Group1 as ABC and Group2 as 1990`
`ABB1900,ABA2000,ATA1990,ATRV2010 should be failed`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Original Problem:**

You may use this regex:

```
^(?:([A-Z])(?!.*\1)){3}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PwSq7U/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `([A-Z])`: Match an uppercase letter and capture in group #1
  - `(?!.*\1)`: Negative lookahead to make sure there is no repeat of same letter anywhere ahead
- `){3}`: End non-capture group. `{3}` makes it match 3 of these
- `$`: End

---

**Updated Problem:** Based on your updated problem you can use this regex to match 3 unique uppercase letters followed by 4 digit year from `1900 to 2019`.

```
^((?:([A-Z])(?![A-Z]*\2)){3})(19\d{2}|20[01]\d)$
```

- `(19\d{2}|20[01]\d)` matches 4 digit year from 1900 to 2019

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/PwSq7U/3)

Comment: The regex works but I also have the year followed after the initial, so I tried using your regex as `^((?:([A-Z])(?!.*\1)){3})(19\d{2}|20[0-1]\d)$` but it isnt working, I just updated the question as well, can you please check?

Comment: I just checked the updated one and noticed its capturing 3 groups `Group1 - ABC`
`Group2 - C` `Group3 - 1990`, but am expecting only 2 groups with `ABC`  and `1990`

Comment: One alternative is to use named groups like this: https://regex101.com/r/PwSq7U/4